# componentDidMount life cycle method is called twice in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

In my react application, the initial API call is made twice when the application gets loaded. I looked at the Network tab in Chrome->inpsect, the 'initiator' call stack is showing that the first call is made from `VM123000_bundle.js` whereas the second call is just made from the actual bundle.js. The same code working in the prod environment except that the Webpack (1.x -> 4.x) and React (15.x->16.x) modules are upgraded. Could someone please point what is the `VM123000_bundle.js` and why it gets called the first time when the home page gets loaded?

AppHome.js

```
componentDidMount () {
const appdata = this.props.ebayHome.toJS();
this.props.getAccounts("/EName/Account/, ActionTypes.ACCOUNT_DATA, JSON.stringify(accountMutualParams));
}
```

Comment: It seems to me that you might have a problem with your webpack config and are somehow importing the App twice.

Comment: thanks @YalungTang, I will check it.

Comment: Could you please shre with us the whole index.js and app.js code ?

Comment: @HosnyBen, thank you for your reply, I am sorry, I could not share them because of company policies, I know it is very difficult to point without looking at the code. But the thing is the same code is working in PROD without duplicated calls, web pack config is completely rewritten for webpack4. so thinking in that perspective. please let me know if there are any known issues with Webpack which causes this issue

Comment: I found the problem but not sure how it works if I remove the reference to bundle.js in my home.html page, it works but the pages are not served from bundle.js, so not sure how to force the app to use the pages from the bundle.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an issue with HtmlWebpackPlugin which actually injects all the generated bundle references into the existing HTML page. There are two ways to fix it.

1. skip injection in webpack config
2. remove the bundle references in the HTML page