# Twice componentDidMount is getting called -(c#-MVC ,react and external babel.js )

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-mvc-4, webpack, babeljs

**Twice componentdiMount is getting called (c#-MVC ,react and external babel.js )**

*This is a similar kind of question 
[componentDidMount life cycle method is called twice in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62119821/componentdidmount-life-cycle-method-is-called-twice-in-react)*

In my project, for few old modules, we are still using external babel.js file
So basically we are integrating c#-MVC, react

I am dividing the question into three parts ,

1. Layout Page C#

_ListLayoutV2.chtml side I have one page , through which I am including babel.js

```
<script src="https://cdn/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js"></script>
```

2. List Page C#

On List page I am including one CarContainer.jsx file
The List page looks like this ,

```
@using Domain.Vault;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = @Resource.CarList;
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_ListLayoutV2.cshtml";
    SiteContext siteContext = WebUtils.GetSiteContext(new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current));
}

@Html.Hidden("hdnGotIt", Resource.GotIt)
@section sectionMain
{
    
    <script type="text/jsx" src="~/Scripts/Area/Travel/Car/CarContainer.jsx">


    </script>
    <div id="main"></div>
}
@section sectionRightSide
{
    @Html.Hidden("hdnDomainUrl", "https://" + Request.Url.Authority)
}
```

3. React Side react

const BLUE_TEXT_COLOR = "#31a8dc";

```
var completeRecordCount = 0;
const REQ_ID = "requestID";
let isfetchInProcess = true;
class CarContainer extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isDataLoaded: false,
            cardata: { content: [] },
            carMatrixData: [],
            isLoading: true,
            currentPage: 1,
            pageSize: 20,
            totalPage: 1,
            carFilter: [],
            carResponses: {},
            brandSort: [{ 'type': 'price', 'order': 'asc' }],
            priceHeaderSelected: false,
            nonFilteredRecordCount: 0,
            filterType: 'none',
            searchType: 'Airport',
            cacheInterval: [],
            resultCount: 0,
            isMoreResultsAvailable: true,
        };

        this.payLaterInterval = 0;
        this.payLaterCount = 0;
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        $('body').addClass('car-list-page');
        if (location.href.indexOf("requestID=0") > 0) {
            //this.searchCarFromList();
        }
        else {
            console.log('componentDidMount')

           // this.loadLegResults();
        }
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
    }

   

    render() {
        
        return (
            <React.StrictMode>
                Hello
           
                </React.StrictMode>
        );
    }
}

const containerElement = document.getElementById("main");
ReactDOM.render(<CarContainer />, containerElement);
```

The screenshot of the chrome browser
[image]

**How can we solve this, so we can call componentdiMount only once**

Answer (score 0):

Once we add the webpack , it started working fine
calling "componentDidMount" only once.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).